# регистр слов в R

Tags: r

Есть вектор с словами

```
 # текст
text <- c("R is a very essential tool for data analysis. While it 
          is regarded as domain specific, it is a very complete programming 
          language. Almost certainly, many people who would benefit from
          using R, do not use it")
# разбиваю текст на вектор сo словами с пом. пакета stringr
text <- unlist(    stringr::str_match_all(text , '\\w+\\b')   )



 text
 [1] "R"           "is"          "a"           "very"        "essential"   "tool"        "for"        
 [8] "data"        "analysis"    "While"       "it"          "is"          "regarded"    "as"         
[15] "domain"      "specific"    "it"          "is"          "a"           "very"        "complete"   
[22] "programming" "language"    "Almost"      "certainly"   "many"        "people"      "who"        
[29] "would"       "benefit"     "from"        "using"       "R"           "do"          "not"        
[36] "use"         "it"
```

Я хочу найти в нем слово "using"

```
text[text=="using"]
[1] "using"
```

все нормально, все находит
но если немножко изменить регистр

```
text[text=="Using"]
character(0)
```

то слово найти уже не получиться

Вопрос как сделать поиск слов не чувствительным к регистру?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию `grep`

```
grep("Using",text,ignore.case=TRUE,value=TRUE)
```

`ignore.case=TRUE`- игнор регистра

`value=TRUE` - Возврат значения из вектора, а не позиции найденного слова

### UPD

`grep` будет искать вхождения. Поэтому поиск "it" вернет не совсем верный результат:

```
grep("it",text,ignore.case=TRUE,value=T,useBytes = T)
```

> [1] "it"      "it"      "benefit" "it"

в этом случае функция `regexpr` отработает лучше:

```
match<-regexpr("IT$",text,ignore.case=TRUE)
text[match==1]
```

> [1] "it" "it" "it"

Answer (score 5):

Достаточно привести слова в векторе к одному регистру:

```
text <- tolower(text)
```

Comment: спасибо всем! вы мне очень помогли